# Can I read a .TXT file with PHP?

Tags: php, file

As I start the process of writing my site in PHP and MySQL, one of the first PHP scripts I've written is a script to initialize my database.  Drop/create the database.  Drop/create each of the tables.  Then load the tables from literals in the script.

That's all working fine!  Whoohoo :-)

But I would prefer to read the data from files rather than hard-code them in the PHP script.

I have a couple of books on PHP, but they're all oriented toward web development using MySQL.  I can't find anything about reading and writing to ordinary files.

Yes, I know there's a gazillion questions here on stackoverflow about reading TXT files, but when I look at each one, they're for C or C# or VB or Perl.  I'm beginning to think that PHP just can't read files :-(

All I need is a brief PHP example of how to open a TXT file on the server, read it sequentially, display the data on the screen, and close the file, as in this pseudo-code:

```
program readfile;
handle = open('myfile.txt');
data = read (handle);
while (not eof (handle)) begin
    display data;
    data = read (handle);
    end;
close (handle);
end;
```

I will also need to write files on the server when I get to the part of my site where people upload avatars, and save them as JPG or GIF files.  But that's for later.

Thanks!

Comment: If you run your initialisation script just once, your data should be in the database and there would be no need to read files any more, right? I also gather you've just started coding in PHP, you should consider bookmarking this great resource: http://php.net/manual/

Comment: "Yes, I know there's a gazillion questions here on stackoverflow about reading TXT files, but when I look at each one, they're for C or C# or VB or Perl. I'm beginning to think that PHP just can't read files :-(" If a question isn't asked on StackOverflow it might also be an indication that it's quite trivial and to be found in an obvious location, e.g. the manual of the programming language. :-)

Comment: But I don't want to embed data in my script.  I want my data in a text file...   And please, Please, PLEASE read my question completely before you give me a snotty answer!!!   I have several books on PHP, and none of them mention file handling.  They all talk about using PHP for web development and don't mention file handling.

Answer (score 28):

From the [PHP manual for `fread()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php):

```
<?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "/usr/local/something.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
?>
```

**EDIT**
per the comment, you can read a file line by line with [`fgets()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's close to what I need.  But I'd prefer to read each line of the file with a separate read so I can parse each line separately with substr.  Having the whole file in one big long string will be a pain to parse.

Comment: @Fredashay you can do that with `fgets`, I've updated my answer

Comment: Yes!  That's exactly what I want :-)  Thanks again!  I wish I could give you an up-ratting, but I'm just a peon here :-(

Answer (score 9):

> All I need is a brief PHP example of how to open a TXT file on the server, read it sequentially, display the data on the screen, and close the file, as in this pseudo-code:

```
echo file_get_contents('/path/to/file.txt');
```

Yes that brief, see [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents), you normally don't need a loop:

```
$file = new SPLFileObject('/path/to/file.txt');
foreach($file as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, since you're asking about resources on the subject, there's a whole book on it in the **[PHP.net docs](http://il.php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php)**.

A basic example:

```
<?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "/usr/local/something.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's close to what I need.  But I'd prefer to read each line of the file with a separate read so I can parse each line separately with substr.  Having the whole file in one big long string will be a pain to parse.

Answer (score 2):

Why you not read php documentation about [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

```
 $file = fopen("source/file.txt","r");
  if(!file)
    {
      echo("ERROR:cant open file");
    }
    else
    {
      $buff = fread ($file,filesize("source/file.txt"));
      print $buff;
    }
```

Comment: php can read files, all you need to do is use `fopen()` and `fread()`, that greatly documented on php.net

Answer (score 1):

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) does all that for you and returns the text file in a string :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to read line by line? Use [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).

```
$handle = @fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($content = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        //echo $content;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```