# Can not create text file with php

Tags: php

I'm very new to php. I'm trying to write a small script that writes a small text file and then reads the same file and show its contents on the screen. But the script always dies, and I get the error message "ERROR: Can not create file!"

I'm running this code in my home CentOS sandbox.

```
<?php
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// http://inpics.net/tutorials/php/files3.html
// PHP Date function:
// http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp
// date("d/m/Y H:i:s")
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Define filename
$myfilename = (date("dMY").".txt");
print "<p>Filename: '<b>$myfilename</b>'</p>";
// Define text
$MyText = 'Some text... blah, blah, blah...';
print "<p>This text should be on the file:'<b>$MyText</b>'</p>";
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Open file for write:
//
$handle = fopen($myfilename, 'w') or die('ERROR: Can not create file!');
fwrite($handle,$MyText,2048);
fclose ($handle);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The code below works, following this example:
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/9861638/4321334
$handle = fopen($myfilename, 'r') or die('ERROR: Can not open file!');
print "<p>Now, let's read the file: <b>$myfilename</b> </p>";
$FileContents = fread($handle,filesize($myfilename));
fclose ($handle);
print "<p>The file <b>'$myfilename'</b> have the following text on it:</p>";
print "<p>$FileContents</p>";
print "<p>Happy ending!</p>";
exit;
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...is the script allowed to write to the directory it's running in? Check the directory permissions of youf OS first. You can also provide a full qualified path, and not only a filename, to specify where the file should be created.

Comment: Oh, and there is no need for the brackets. `$myfilename = date("dMY").".txt";` will do.

Comment: It's work fine in my windows xampp, Please check the directory/file permission in your app root in  CentOS (may be write permission off for your app). You may check it via terminal/Command Line by using "ls -la" or you may add full file permission to test like chmod -R 777 directory_name

Comment: @xph: The script is running inside the /var/www/html/ folder, this script is intended to be called by a web page.

Comment: @xph: thanks for the brackets suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `file_put_contents`, it achieve similar goal, its just a wrapper for `fwrite`

```
file_put_contents($myfilename, $MyText);
```

Comment: For some estrange reason, the line that you suggested only creates a "empty" file, no matter the file or folder permissions. Running from the console does the same.

Comment: @Marco-LuisSALCEDOTOVAR check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php