# Opening txt in Php

Tags: php, html

Hi I was trying to make a php file that is like a chat system where I can enter text and above it have it echo the previous entries. In my text file it is displayed with breaks at the end of the but when using

```
echo file_get_contents("example.txt")
```

the file just get displayed without the breaks at the end of each line if there another option to display it like in my txt file?

Comment: `echo '<pre>';` right before.

Comment: @DaveChen you are right but it is for debug not for real reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many things wrong with the code.

If you're writing the file with your PHP script, then make sure that you are using double quotes. Which means the following is **correct**:

```
<?php fwrite($your_file, "Text to write \n in your file"); ?>
```

But this **isn't**:

```
<?php fwrite($your_file, 'Text to write \n in your file'); ?>
```

Single quotes will write the literal character `\n` instead of a new line because single quotes don't usually process the string you give them.

Secondly, when you are reading the file using `file_get_contents("your_file.txt");`, you'll get a string which doesn't contain characters like \n.

The PHP doc says

> file_get_contents() - Reads entire file into a string

So to solve this, wrap the string to echo in a `<pre>` tag like:

```
<?php echo "<pre>" . file_get_contents("your_file.txt") . "</pre>";
```

The `<pre>` tag outputs a pre-formatted string, meaning exactly what it was given.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you I have never heard of the <pre> tags in html before this. It is now layed out exactly how I want it!

Answer (score 2):

try this, I think it will give you output as you want

```
echo $string= preg_replace("/\n/", "<br>", file_get_contents('sample.txt'));
```

Comment: the `nl2br()` function would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Doc says

> file_get_contents() - Reads entire file into a string

e.g. this converts body of file to string but the (invisible equivalent of) \n is not a string char

try [foopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) function instead.

```
$handle = fopen("/home/rasmus/file.txt", "r");
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this one :

```
echo file_get_contents('./people.txt', true);
```

You can refer this page:

[**LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861603/can-i-read-a-txt-file-with-php)

**OR**

[**REFER THIS PAGE**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)